# method name expected error on String.Format()

Tags: c#

I've recently started learning c# having no prior experience in programming, I have created this super simple script for calculating the cost of materials for a window installation however on the line with the String.Format("{0:0.##}" Visual Studio is giving me an error - 'Method name expected'. Any help would be amazing as I couldn't find a specific enough solution anywhere. Note it is all enclosed in a class and in the Main() method if that could somehow affect it.

```
    Console.Write("How wide is the window in metres: ");
    decimal frameWidth = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());


    Console.Write("How tall is the window in metres? ");
    decimal frameHeight = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    decimal glassArea = (frameWidth *  frameHeight) ;
    decimal woodLength = (frameWidth * 2) + (frameHeight * 2);

    Console.WriteLine("You will need " + glassArea + "m squared of glass and " + woodLength + "m of wood.");

    Console.Write("What is the current cost of glass per square metre? £");
    decimal gCost = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("What is the current cost of wood per metre? £");
    decimal wCost = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

    decimal totalCost = String.Format("{0:0.##}"((glassArea * gCost) + (woodLength * wCost)));
    Console.WriteLine("The total cost for the required materials is £" + totalCost );
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing a comma

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}" ,//<--
             ((glassArea * gCost) + (woodLength * wCost)));
```

Answer (score 3):

arguments need to be comma separated, so you would have to change

```
decimal totalCost = String.Format("{0:0.##}"((glassArea * gCost) + (woodLength * wCost)));
```

into

```
decimal totalCost = String.Format("{0:0.##}", ((glassArea * gCost) + (woodLength * wCost)));
```

I did not check for other errors.